# Error: Client received SOAP Fault from server: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, soap, nullpointerexception, jax-ws

I'm writing the JAX-WS Web Service. When I'm running my Remote Web Service Client code, I receive the next error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client
> received SOAP Fault from server: java.lang.NullPointerException Please
> see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the
> failure.  at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:116)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:238)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:189)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:276)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:104)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:77)
> at
> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:147)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getShoes(Unknown Source)  at
> org.example.shoesshop.client.ShoesServiceClient.main(ShoesServiceClient.java:32)

Here's the code of Remote Web Service Client:

```
public class ShoesServiceClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ShoesNotFound_Exception{
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
        System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
        
        URL wsdl = new URL("file:///" + new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/shoesservice.wsdl");
        
        ShoesServiceImpl service = new ShoesService(wsdl).getShoesPort();
        service.getShoes(1); // ShoesServiceClient.java:32 is here
    }
}
```

Also sharing the code of Web Service Publisher (the address is localhost:8080/shoesservice)

```
public class ShoesServicePublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String addr = "http://localhost:8080/shoesservice";
        final Object impl = new ShoesServiceImpl();
        Endpoint shoesPub = Endpoint.publish(addr, impl);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        shoesPub.stop();
    }
}
```

Here's the image of TCP/IP Monitor Configuration
[TCP/IP Monitor Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03FML.png)

The wsdl-file has the next structure (it is stored on my project folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes" name="Shoes">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.org/ShoesShop" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/shoesservice?xsd=1"></xsd:import>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/shoesservice?xsd=2"></xsd:import>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getShoes">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getShoes"></part>
</message>
<message name="getShoesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getShoesResponse"></part>
</message>
<message name="ShoesNotFound">
<part name="fault" element="tns:ShoesNotFound"></part>
</message>
<message name="getAllShoes">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllShoes"></part>
</message>
<message name="getAllShoesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllShoesResponse"></part>
</message>
<message name="updateShoes">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:updateShoes"></part>
</message>
<message name="updateShoesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:updateShoesResponse"></part>
</message>
<message name="addShoes">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:addShoes"></part>
</message>
<message name="addShoesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:addShoesResponse"></part>
</message>
<message name="ShoesAlreadyExists">
<part name="fault" element="tns:ShoesAlreadyExists"></part>
</message>
<message name="deleteShoes">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteShoes"></part>
</message>
<message name="deleteShoesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteShoesResponse"></part>
</message>
<message name="countShoes">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:countShoes"></part>
</message>
<message name="countShoesResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:countShoesResponse"></part>
</message>
<portType name="ShoesServiceImpl">
<operation name="getShoes">
<input wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/getShoesRequest" message="tns:getShoes"></input>
<output wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/getShoesResponse" message="tns:getShoesResponse"></output>
<fault message="tns:ShoesNotFound" name="ShoesNotFound" wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/getShoes/Fault/ShoesNotFound"></fault>
</operation>
<operation name="getAllShoes">
<input wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/getAllShoesRequest" message="tns:getAllShoes"></input>
<output wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/getAllShoesResponse" message="tns:getAllShoesResponse"></output>
</operation>
<operation name="updateShoes">
<input wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/updateShoesRequest" message="tns:updateShoes"></input>
<output wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/updateShoesResponse" message="tns:updateShoesResponse"></output>
<fault message="tns:ShoesNotFound" name="ShoesNotFound" wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/updateShoes/Fault/ShoesNotFound"></fault>
</operation>
<operation name="addShoes">
<input wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/addShoesRequest" message="tns:addShoes"></input>
<output wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/addShoesResponse" message="tns:addShoesResponse"></output>
<fault message="tns:ShoesAlreadyExists" name="ShoesAlreadyExists" wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/addShoes/Fault/ShoesAlreadyExists"></fault>
</operation>
<operation name="deleteShoes">
<input wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/deleteShoesRequest" message="tns:deleteShoes"></input>
<output wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/deleteShoesResponse" message="tns:deleteShoesResponse"></output>
<fault message="tns:ShoesNotFound" name="ShoesNotFound" wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/deleteShoes/Fault/ShoesNotFound"></fault>
</operation>
<operation name="countShoes">
<input wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/countShoesRequest" message="tns:countShoes"></input>
<output wsam:Action="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes/ShoesServiceImpl/countShoesResponse" message="tns:countShoesResponse"></output>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ShoesPortBinding" type="tns:ShoesServiceImpl">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"></soap:binding>
<operation name="getShoes">
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</output>
<fault name="ShoesNotFound">
<soap:fault name="ShoesNotFound" use="literal"></soap:fault>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="getAllShoes">
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="updateShoes">
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</output>
<fault name="ShoesNotFound">
<soap:fault name="ShoesNotFound" use="literal"></soap:fault>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="addShoes">
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</output>
<fault name="ShoesAlreadyExists">
<soap:fault name="ShoesAlreadyExists" use="literal"></soap:fault>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="deleteShoes">
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</output>
<fault name="ShoesNotFound">
<soap:fault name="ShoesNotFound" use="literal"></soap:fault>
</fault>
</operation>
<operation name="countShoes">
<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="Shoes">
<port name="ShoesPort" binding="tns:ShoesPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:18080/shoesservice"></soap:address>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

When I launch the TCP/IP Monitor with running Remote Web Service Client code, I get the next messages in XML format:

Request Message

```
<?xml version="1.0"  standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns3:getShoes xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/ShoesShop" xmlns:ns3="http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes">
<arg0>1</arg0>
</ns3:getShoes>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Response Message

```
<?xml version="1.0"  standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
</S:Fault>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Here's the code of ShoesService Class:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Shoes", targetNamespace = "http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/shoesservice?wsdl")
public class ShoesService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL SHOES_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException SHOES_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName SHOES_QNAME = new QName("http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes", "Shoes");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/shoesservice?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        SHOES_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        SHOES_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public ShoesService() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), SHOES_QNAME);
    }

    public ShoesService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), SHOES_QNAME, features);
    }

    public ShoesService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SHOES_QNAME);
    }

    public ShoesService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SHOES_QNAME, features);
    }

    public ShoesService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public ShoesService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "ShoesPort")
    public ShoesServiceImpl getShoesPort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes", "ShoesPort"), ShoesServiceImpl.class);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "ShoesPort")
    public ShoesServiceImpl getShoesPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://shoeshop.example/jaxws/shoes", "ShoesPort"), ShoesServiceImpl.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (SHOES_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw SHOES_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return SHOES_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

In addition, sharing the code of GetShoes class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getShoes", propOrder = {
    "arg0"
})
public class GetShoes {
    protected int arg0;
    public int getArg0() {
        return arg0;
    }
    public void setArg0(int value) {
        this.arg0 = value;
    }
}
```

and GetShoesResponse class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getShoesResponse", propOrder = {
    "_return"
})
public class GetShoesResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    protected Shoes _return;
    public Shoes getReturn() {
        return _return;
    }
    public void setReturn(Shoes value) {
        this._return = value;
    }
}
```

If you need more information, please let me know

Comment: I got exactly same issue but no answer here

Comment: Same for me... did you figure it out?